# Оптимальный алгоритм: Сортировка строк

Tags: алгоритм

Имеется: JSON файл с чат-историей, отсортированный хронологически.

Это как лог моих персональных чатов с разными людьми, и из-за того, что история хронологическая, одним списком - нет "диалогов", все перемешано.

Хочется: отсортировать и по диалогом и по времени.

Pseudo-code:

```
convert JSON file into array/slice of structures = easy
structure[] items contain:
   sender.ID, receiver.ID, timestamp, message

go through the list/structure[] and 
for each item check sender.ID and receiver.ID
  add either sender.ID or receiver.ID to the uniq.set 
done
for each uniq.ID in uniq.set 
  go through the same structure[] and get message
done
```

Проблема видится в том, что надо много раз проходиться по тому же самому списку (по количеству уникальных корреспондентов...)

Можно как-то улучшить?

Answer (score 3):

Вообще это за 1 проход делается... Самый наверное правильный вариант - без копирования самих элементов. Пишу на псевдо-С. Как получить id диалога - вам виднее (например склеить sender.ID и receiver.ID)

```
@input list< dialog_id, body > input
map<int, list<int> > dialog_block

for (item : list)
    dialog_block[ item.dialog_id ].add(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку все сообщения отсортированы хронологически - все можно сделать в один проход.

На входе у вас список сообщений, на выходе - хэштаблица (словарь), где ключ - идентификатор собеседника, а значение - упорядоченный по времени список сообщений.

Для каждого сообщения:

1. Проверяйте есть ли собеседник в хэштаблице.

   - если нет - добавляйте новый пустой список в хэштаблицу.
2. Получаете из хэштаблицы список сообщений текущего собеседника
3. Добавляете в конец списка текущее сообщение.

Если вдруг доступны списки только с дорогим добавлением в конец - можно идти от последнего сообщения к первому и наращивать списки с головы.